# IP Address mapping in Windows Host file

Tags: ip, mapping, windows-xp, host

I have a IP address which is map to a domain , and that particular domain name is hard-coded in the application . this domain is the back-end web server for my application.

Now my back end Service is being changed to another server in cloud, unfortunatily i lost my source code of one of the applications. Now i want to point the same domain name which was hard-coded in the application to to new IP address in the cloud.

Old IP        > 62.215.XX.YZ  > Poin To > Jidh.in
New Service   > 52.174.XX.YY

Here, When i call [jidh.in](http://jidh.in) i can access a file/ service  inside  **62.215.XX.YZ** .

Similarly, now i want to access the new service/file in cloud ,   where its IP in server is **52.174.XX.YY**. Same time i am unable to change the domain name jidh.in also.
I am doing this in Windows-Xp's Host File .
Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

you can change host file in winOS
open this file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
add a new line at the end (eg)

```
 52.174.XX.YY jidh.in
```

ok,your application is worked,but only is this computer. haha..